# Routing traffic between namespace without Istio to namespace with Istio

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

In my cluster I have multiple namespaces. All my 1st-party services are running in one namespace and all 3rd-party services are running in their own namespaces.

I have Istio enabled on my 1st-party namespace (let’s call it `ns-1` ). Istio is not enabled for any of my 3rd-party namespaces.

I have a 3rd-party service that needs to connect to my 1st-party service. The 3rd-party service will use k8s DNS like `service1.ns-1.svc.cluster.local` to connect to my service. The 3rd-party service can communicate to my 1st-party service without TLS. When I enable TLS between the service it fails and I don’t know how/where to terminate the TLS?

Is it possible to define a `Gateway` that can route traffic between namespaces? or it is possible to route traffic between namespaces through Istio `IngressGateway`

Comment: Did you try setting mTLS mode to `PERMISSIVE` for this specific workload, like in the [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#enable-mutual-tls-per-workload)?

Comment: this didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with Istio & Minikube with echo-server exams this is what I found. First let me define the namespaces and services so it will be easy to explain

- `ns-1` - namespace 1 with Istio enabled
- `ns-2` - namespace 2 without Istio
- `service-1` - service 1 in `ns-1` namespace
- `service-2`- service 2 in `ns-2` namespace

Below are connections status between these 2 services

- `service-1` can communicate to `service-2.ns-2.svc.cluster.local` with no TLS
- `service-2` can communicate to `service-1.ns-1.svc.cluster.local` with no TLS
- `service-1` can communicate to `service-2.ns-2.svc.cluster.local` with TLS
- `service-2` **cannot** communicate to `service-1.ns-1.svc.cluster.local` with TLS

You may know already in 4th case above (`service-2` with TLS) the TLS is not terminated by any Istio objects which is causing this to failure.

If the TLS can be terminate by a sidecar this can work. [added tls to sidecar api](https://github.com/istio/api/pull/2165) is what I am looking for but it is not in current Istio release (1.12.2 as of this answer)

What I ended up doing?

I deployed another istio-ingressGateway with service type as ClusterIP set it to route traffic for my ports. This will be the gateway for all my 3rd-party services to reach my 1st-party services and it will terminate TLS for incoming traffic and do mTLS to services in the istio namespace (`ns-1`). Since this is a ClusterIP it will be visible only inside the cluster. I then configured Istio `Gateway` and `VirtualService` objects to route traffic to my services based on port numbers.